# what are the factors in TV that affects video quality in cable tv/dish satellite tv in bigger(65 Iinch) 4K TV screens

Tags: 4k, cable, full-hd, television

I happened to visit a TV show room which had so many big TVs(55,65,70,75 inch TVs, Sony Bravia , Samsung , LG , TLC etc..) with amazing technologies such as

```
LED
OLED
QLED
QNED
NANO
```

and amazing resolutions like FHD,UHD,4k and 8k

with different back panels such as Edge lit and back lit.

I played videos from Netflix,amazon prime , hotstar etc.. on these TVs I can see the video clarity is good I mean it's not pixelating and video quality is good and admirable.

But when I play TV channels either from Cable operator or premium high quality DTH(Direct to Home) Dish satellite , I can see the videos are pix-elating regardless of TV technology such as premium OLED

Most of the TV channels in my country is either SD or HD only.

Even I played some HD TV channels and the video clarity is horrible even in the TVs which they claim they have separate chip for up-scaling.

What are the other factors that we should be aware of while buying TV ? so I can choose the right TV and watch HD TV channels in 4k 65 inch TV with good quality

Comment: My comment on the now deleted cross-post still stands. If you're getting pixellation on any half decent modern TV, it's in the broadcast, not the TV.